# SIFT prediction

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, sift

I am using the SIFT implementation of Andrea Vedaldi, to calculate the sift descriptors of two images. But I would like to know if it is possible to predict where the object will be in next image, using SIFT descriptors.

Comment: This hasn't got to do with matlab. Be more specific.

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible, but SIFT descriptors are just one part of the method and not very related to prediction, but to detection.

You need to use SIFT for detection.

Once you detect the object, you preform the **prediction** step and **update** step with, for example, [Kalman Filter](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2007/Kim-ObjectTrackingInAVideoSequence.pdf).

Comment: +1 for Kalman. It is the canonical way for this kind of problem.

Comment: I have another question, can i calculate vector displacement from the object using that implementation?

Comment: What do you mean for vector displacement?

Comment: I mean, i need to calculate the displacement from the object, if i have a matching from the images i can calculate the movement. Example, in the first image i have a keypoint in (2,4), in second i have the same keypoint(a matching?) in (4,5), so i could get the displacement. But I don´t know if matches return that displacement.

Comment: You can open a new question for further info, but I will try to explain it here. SIFT will give you matches of the object in one frame as (x,y) coordinates. In the next frame you will have a different number of matches, but of course many of them will be the same. I guess the displacement vector you mean will be the difference between the position vectors in 2 frames. But it will be a 2D displacement, if you want a 3D one, you'll need to use homography matrix and those camera transformations. I suggest you to read about the topic casue it is extense, xd

Comment: Ok, thanks!Yes, I need that. I´m interested in 2D displacement, but i don´t how i can give that difference from that code, i mean the variable which return that difference.

Comment: Well it is the the difference between to vector positions of the same match over 2 consecutive frames. I don't know if there is a function in matlab that ouputs this, I don't think so, but it is easy to program ir. I usually work with openCV. Why don't you have a look to the related functions, maybe you get things clearer:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/features2d_common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html

Comment: Note that the distance in that function is the "error" between the "train image" and the "detected image" for one match, not the displacement

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.
In fact, There is a method called HOG. HOG 's descriptors is a upgraded version of SIFT's descriptors.
The HOG algorithm has been widely used in detection.